# Why won't Scala recognize that I'm extending ListModel<E>?

Tags: swing, scala, generics

I am writing my own `javax.swing.ListModel<E>`:

```
class Category(...)
class CategoryListModel extends javax.swing.ListModel[Category] {
    // not shown: ListModel[Category] interface methods implemented here
    ...
}
```

However, when I try to set the list model with:

```
val myList: JList = ...
myList.setModel(new CategoryListModel)
```

The compiler gives me this error:

```
type mismatch;
 found   : CategoryListModel
 required: javax.swing.ListModel[?0] where type ?0
     myList.setModel(new CategoryListModel)
```

I thought `CategoryListModel` did implement `ListModel[Category]`??? I am trying to learn Scala by practicing using it lately, but I don't know how to interperet this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so the error was originating in the fact that my `JList` did not have a type parameter specified (it was generated by a GUI builder).  I changed the declaration to:

```
JList<Category> // this particular file is a Java file
```

Now everything works.